# How do I run a mac exe on another computer if I'm using frameworks?

Tags: c++, xcode, frameworks

My ultimate goal is simply to **get the program to run on another Mac.**

When using Visual Studio, you can compile an exe that will run anywhere as long as its dll's are in the same folder.   **How can I do something similar on a Mac with framework files?**

It's a c++ program that I'm compiling with Xcode 7.

Comment: My current situation is that every time I try to run the unix-exe on another mac, it looks for the directory path from my computer.  
I tried getting Xcode to compile using frameworks in a single folder in the base Hard Drive directory that was on both computers.  
This didn't work and it's not really what I want to make the user have to do.

Comment: I found this: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPFrameworks/Tasks/CreatingFrameworks.html , but I don't really understand it and I'm not sure if it will help.

Comment: This link seems to offer a solution, but I believe it's instructions are describing an outdated version of Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that those frameworks aren't on the other Mac…
In that case you should package your app as an application bundle with the frameworks in the bundle's /Contents/Frameworks/ folder (and the executable in the /Contents/MacOS/ folder and a Info.plist file in the /Contents folder).